# No route matches [GET] "/members/sign_out Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I use rails 4.1.0 and Devise. I've setup devise on `Member` model class and when I click "log out" link as bellow:

```
<%= link_to "Log out", destroy_member_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

I get the following error only on production environment:

> No route matches [GET] "/members/sign_out Devise

Note: I've precompiled my assets and include the following in my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: Syntactically, it looks right to me. You have devise on `Member` class only, right?

Comment: It looks to me like the jQuery UJS isn’t working. That’s what notices the `:method => :delete` and makes the form submit with that method. Can you see that jQuery and jQuery UJS are actually loading in your browser?

Comment: @kiddorails No , I have devise on User and Member

Comment: @BuckDoyle I checked and found that jQuery and jQuery UJS are actually loading in browser

Comment: @AhmedShawky Does `rake routes` gives this route to you?

Comment: What does the HTML for the `link_to` look like?

Comment: @kiddorails , Yes and as i mentioned in the question the route work in development but not work in production

Comment: @BuckDoyle <a data-method="delete" href="/members/sign_out?locale=en" rel="nofollow">Log out</a>

Comment: Yeah. But the link is being followed with `GET` rather than `DELETE`, which is what makes me say UJS isn’t working. Are there any errors in your Javascript console?

Comment: @BuckDoyle No errors in Javascript console

Comment: Hmm, I can’t suggest anything more than that the UJS isn’t working without being able to look at the Javascript myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you do not have the `gem jquery-ujs` installed or you are not calling the resulting javascript in your application via `= javascript_include_tag "application"`, the response will be sent as a GET request, and the route will fail.

Check options below to make it work:

1. In  `devise.rb` Change `config.sign_out_via` = `:get` (not
   recommended, since DELETE is the appropriate RESTful way to use this)

   ```
   config.sign_out_via = :delete
   ```
2. Use button instead of `link_to` to

   ```
   = button_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete)
   ```

   With button_to Rails will do the heavy lifting on making the proper DELETE call. You can
   then style the button to look like a link if you wish.
3. In your routes.rb

   ```
   devise_for :members do
     get '/members /sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes.rb` the order should be this

```
devise_for :members
resources :members
```

`resources :members` should come under `devise_for :members`